# Select community when creating a new question

Tags: feature-request, questions, migration

As a regular of sqa.stackexchange.com I often see questions asked that have no relevance to Quality Assurance or Testing. We vote the questions as off-topic or try to get a moderator to migrate it to the correct SE community.

I have the feeling some new users do not understand that SE is cut up in different communities and land on a SE site from a search engine and think lets asks a question and hit the button, fill out the forms and be done with it. This leads to a lot of extra work and un-answered questions. It does not feel very user friendly and might costs users that never return because of it.

Possible solutions:

- The "Ask Question" form should include a clear indication about in what community you are going to post a question and an option to select an other community to post it in instead.
- New users are forced to go through a sort of tour explaining the use of communities and are assisted in moving to the correct one to ask their question in.
- Easier way for regulars to migrate question to the correct community, since now this is moderator only. Maybe a vote system, just like closing, but then for migrations

Comment: *Sigh* This isn't about not *knowing*, it's about not *reading*. People don't read what's there for them. Heck, I myself read all of the stuff in the help center way after when I should have.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani has a really good point. I've got 20k network wide, and i still need to read all of the help. Call it my summer project...

Comment: [Semi-related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22051/should-we-allow-self-migration-of-questions), for when you get the wrong site and are pointed towards the right one.

Answer (score 8):

> The "Ask Question" form should include a clear indication about in what community you are going to post a question

Looks pretty clear what community this is to me:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> and an option to select an other community to post it in instead.

There is the footer with all the communities in it:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And the dropdown:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> New users are forced to go through a sort of tour explaining the use of communities and are assisted in moving to the correct one to ask their question in.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> Easier way for regulars to migrate question to the correct community, since now this is moderator only. Maybe a vote system, just like closing, but then for migrations

[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250)

> Any user with 3,000 reputation can vote to migrate a question to another site via a list of up to five sites, which are most relevant to that site. Simply load the close dialog, select the off-topic because close reason, and then select belongs on another site in the off-topic reason list.
>
> If you don't have 3,000 reputation or the site isn't in the list of available migration targets, you can also flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you.

Comment: Although it seems clear that your are in Ubuntu, its not clear the question is NOT shared over the community network. Maybe move the how to ask to the left. The footer is not visible on my 1920x1080 resolution screen. Not sure the dropdown is a lot of help for first time visitors. I have 4.000+ rep, but I can select only two sites when voting for offtopic. I will research how I can increase this list of sites with our moderators, thanks. With all the options you pointed out new users still post questions in the wrong community, so maybe it does need some usability testing and improvement :)

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal I think it's the new user's fault, not the system's fault. 1) It's pretty clear, it showing that I'm asking on the ubuntu site - not another site 2) I've got the same screen size, scroll down 3) maybe not 4) that's the site's preferences, speak to the mods.

Answer (score 3):

> The "Ask Question" form should include a clear indication about in what community you are going to post a question and an option to select an other community to post it in instead.

I am pretty sure you stay in your site when asking your question so this cannot be an issue in the first place, as explained by Tim with his screenshot. Directly above the bodies, there is the logo for the site and its name.

If you still argue that that is not clear enough after scrolling down, on the right side of the bodies, you can see a subtitle saying:

> Is your question about..."site's topic here"

It is pretty clear on where you are supposed to ask. If you still argue, then I think you are going a little too far on whether they can see what you are supposed to ask about. *And* there is a Help Center link that can help you ask the right question on your site.

And about the last part, if you go to the bottom of the page, you can see the entire list of sites you can post your question on.

[image]

> New users are forced to go through a sort of tour explaining the use of communities and are assisted in moving to the correct one to ask their question in.

We already have that in place for new users here and probably in every other site. Thank you Tim again for that perfect example of what I mean.

> Easier way for regulars to migrate question to the correct community, since now this is moderator only. Maybe a vote system, just like closing, but then for migrations

You can flag for moderator attention for the flagged question to be migrated. You just need 15 rep for that. The link is 5 years old so some of the information might need to be updated: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250) Anyways, moderators have the ***final decision*** but users can ***flag for migration***. So, this is not really moderator only here.

> As a regular of sqa.stackexchange.com I often see questions asked that have no relevance to Quality Assurance or Testing. We vote the questions as off-topic or try to get a moderator to migrate it to the correct SE community.

Well, at least we know we can count on you to protect that site from potential spammers and random questions. New users sometimes just ignore the tour and don't read the helpful introduction so they ask the wrong thing. Sometimes, they just join a random site and ask questions like it is Yahoo answers or ask.com.

Just leave a helpful comment telling the new users to visit the Help Center so they can ask a better, on-topic question next time.

> I have the feeling some new users do not understand that SE is cut up in different communities and land on a SE site from a search engine and think lets asks a question and hit the button, fill out the forms and be done with it.

Correct, people have done that before and it's not fun for anyone, the viewer nor the asker. As said before, leave a helpful comment and steer them into the correct direction. We love to help new users out, and who knows? They might become a rising star in your community faster than you think.

So to sum this up, be a good person and steer the person in the right direction. Some people just don't understand how we work and they just need a little push into the right direction. We already set up our little "security system" to try to help users indirectly. So will you help us steer the new users in the right direction with the rest of your fellow community members?

Answer (score 3):

> The "Ask Question" form should include a clear indication about in
>   what community you are going to post a question

They already do, on the right hand side. For example, Programmers site has:

[image: programmers-ask-question-side]

"Is your question about software development".
If their answer to that is "no" then it's up to them to find out where is. The links are already there for them.

We can only help people so much, the sites have a lot of info all over the page, some of it is required to cater for *other things*, and we cannot *signpost* everything everywhere for users.

> and an option to select an other community to post it in instead.

But how could we do this?
Do we list *all* other "possible communities" right there?
Or, somehow magically know where they would prefer to ask?
Or, let them do a little bit of leg work and find out where they want to ask themselves?

The "ask a question" is just that. It's not "find me a relevant site", or "list all possible communities", or "teach me about Stack network". It's a function to "ask a question".

There are other things a user *might do* in the "ask a question" area - for example ask a dupe, we already provide for that.
They might not use markdown properly, we already assist with that.
But we cannot hold their hand on *everything*.

---

> New users are forced to go through a sort of tour explaining the use
>   of communities and are assisted in moving to the correct one to ask
>   their question in.

Yes, they are, already.

How can we make that any clearer or simpler than it already is? 
If people don't want to look and read how a site works, you could shove a huge pop-up in their face which covers their entire screen stating "If you don't read the help section and tour you won't know how to use the site -click here and here".

Most people will look for the little x to close it and still not bother.

---

> Easier way for regulars to migrate question to the correct community,
>   since now this is moderator only. Maybe a vote system, just like
>   closing, but then for migrations

This has already been suggested in various other feature requests.
The problem is, with no offence to fellow Stackies, people don't really know where to migrate things to.
And a lot of uses just want the crap outta *their* site, so send it wherever it might be border-line relevant.

We then end up with not only each site playing pass-the-turd, but the user who asked the question will just be baffled to death.