# If I delete a question, will it count towards the 50 questions a month limit or not?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, deleted-questions, rate-limiting

On Stack Overflow you can ask 50 questions in 30 days. If I ask a question and delete it, will it be treated as an asked question or not? Will I have 49  opportunities to ask a question left, or 50?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it counts, i.e. if you ask a question and delete it you'll still have only 49 to go. But sadly couldn't find official confirmation for this yet.

Comment: Deleting questions doesn't help to circumvent [another rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286069/295232), so my guess is it won't help here either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, even if deleted, the question will still count towards the limit.

Proof can be seen in [this question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315840/cant-post-my-50th-question-in-30-days) where the OP couldn't post the 50<sup>th</sup> question and the [reply from an SE staff member](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315840/cant-post-my-50th-question-in-30-days#comment301223_315840) is:

> You have a question from January 8 which you deleted.