# Wait for question to close before rejecting migration

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, off-topic, on-hold

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1192089/google-hangouts-account-disconnection) question was recently asked on superuser, flagged as off topic and migrated to WebApps StackExchange ([Google Hangouts Account Disconnection](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104545/google-hangouts-account-disconnection)), all of which makes perfect sense, since the question is about a Web app, Google Hangouts. On WebApps, the question was put on hold because it was unclear, which again is true. If I understand correctly, putting the question on hold automatically caused the migration to be rejected.

However, I believe that the purpose of putting a question on hold is to allow for time for an edit to be made to fix the problem before the question is closed. If the question should be migrated, but still is not a complete question, shouldn't it be kept around on the migrated site as editable?

To me, it would make more sense to keep the migration until the question is closed, and at least make the question editable. Of course, the question linked is not the perfect example, but if a question clearly should be migrated but also should be edited, doesn't it make more sense to allow edits to be made while the question is on hold or even closed, at least until the question is deleted?

**EDIT**: Seems like a good resource for migration information is [A proposed philosophy of question migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration)

Comment: as a SU mod. Meh. Its not a great question, and the migration rejection was appropriate. We shouldn't really have migrated it.

Comment: Only gems should be migrated.  If a question is not a gem and it's not on topic then it should it should be polished into a gem before it's migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the question should be migrated, but still is not a complete question, shouldn't it be kept around on the migrated site as editable?

No, not really. Before migrating, the people who migrate should check that the question fits the other site, and is NOT in bad form. If unclear, it should be closed as such on the source site, not be migrated.

The users of the target site should not clean the mess left for them by users of the source site.

Comment: Just to clarify, a question should be a good question *before* migration, not after, correct?

Comment: @Panda yes, exactly.

Comment: Slightly related, should a user asking this kind of question edit the original question and hope for it to be migrated so the old answers can be kept, or simply ask a new question on the target site?

Comment: @Panda good question. Ideally, the OP will edit on the source site, then flag as "other" and ask to migrate. If the answer(s) got upvotes, OP can't delete anyway, and cross-site asking isn't accepted very well. As the one who answered I'm afraid you don't have much you can do though.

Comment: This is a nice idea in principle, but it never actually works out this way. There's no feedback for closevoters on the source site, so they will *always* happily send junk over, limited only by occasional whining posts on their meta to try to get them to shape up through expostulation.

Comment: @NathanTuggy true, but nothing we can do about it, except  advice against it. :)